# Is there an algorithm for numerical approximation of (naive) period integrals

Tags: nt.number-theory, na.numerical-analysis, approximation-algorithms

Let $d$ be an integer, and let
$f_1, \ldots, f_m$ and $g_1, \ldots, g_n$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X_1,\ldots,X_d]$
be rational polynomials.
Then
$$D = \{ (x_i)_{i=1}^d \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid f_j(x_1,\ldots,x_d) = 0 \text{ and } g_j(x_1,\ldots,x_d) \le 0\}$$
is a so-called semialgebraic set.
Let $\phi \colon D \to \mathbb{R}$ be a rational function without poles in $D$.
(That is, $\phi$ is the quotient of two polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[X_1,\ldots,X_d]$, and the denominator has no zeros in $D$.

If $D$ is bounded (i.e., compact) then the integral $\int_D \phi \,\mathrm{d}\mu$ (where $\mathrm{d}\mu$ is a $\dim(D)$-dimensional form) is definite, and one may attempt to evaluate it. This ties in with the period conjecture which many people believe to be out of reach at the moment. (See the survey paper “Periods” by Kontsevich and Zagier for details.)

One may also attempt to numerically approximate the integral. That is what my question is about.

> 1. Is there an algorithm (probabilistic?) that approximates $\int_D \phi\,\mathrm{d}\mu$?

Observe that one may assume that $\phi = 1$, by adding an extra dimension. So the question essentially boils down to the following one.

> 2. Is there an algorithm to approximate the volume of $D$?

Such an algorithm may take as input the polynomials $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ and $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ mentioned above. It should determine whether $D$ is bounded, and what its (generic) dimension is. Finally, it should compute the volume of $D$.

(For example, if $D$ has the same dimension $d$ as the ambient space, then one may use a Monte-Carlo algorithm [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration] to approximate the volume of $D$. I don't see how to apply this in general.)

I would think this question has been solved long ago (even if the performance might be miserable). However my search through the literature/internet did not give a general solution. Any pointers are very welcome.

---

It might be helpful to give some examples of semi-algebraic sets.
One of the easiest non-trivial examples is $D_1 = \{ (x,y) \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Of course, the volume (i.e., length) of $D_1$ is $2\pi$. We can modify this example by also adding an inequality, for example
$D_2 = \{ (x,y) \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1 \text{ and } xy \ge 0 \}$. Note that $D_2$ consists of two quarter-circles, and therefore has volume $\pi$.

Of course these examples are still rather trivial. One of the important points is that the dimension of $D$ may be smaller than the dimension of the ambient space, and $D$ might be disconnected.

Comment: You can construct a random walk on D whose stationary distribution is the uniform distribution on D.  To this end, reject any steps of the walk out of D. The empirical average of $\phi$ along this walk will converge to your desired integral.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee, Wouldn't the random walk step out of $D$ with probability 1, if the dimension of $D$ is lower than the ambient dimension? Think about the circle ${ x^2 + y^2 = 1}$ inside $\mathbb{R}^2$. I don't see how to apply the random walk.

Comment: It looks like $D$ has a boundary. If the walk steps out of $D$
 through this boundary, that is with its current state in the interior of $D$
 and its next step in the exterior of $D$, then reject this move. Otherwise, one should construct all of the steps of the walk to lie in $D$
 via, e.g., projection. To take your example, the unit circle is boundaryless, so the forward/backward steps of a walk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ have to both be designed to lie in the circle.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a concrete instance of your general problem?  One that illustrates the structure of D  — just a suggestion.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee, Using projections to get back into $D$ might be a good idea. I will have to think about how to do that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Of course, if the dimension of $D$ is less than $d$, then the $d$-dimensional volume of $D$ is zero ...

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee, sure – so I'm looking for the $\dim(D)$-dimensional volume…

Comment: However, $\int_D \phi d \mu$ looks like the integral of $\phi$ with respect to  $d\mu$, which seems to be the standard volume form on $\mathbb{R}^d$, not $D$.  If the dimension of $D$ is less then $d$, then this is equal to zero.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee, hmmm, you are right. I actually want $\phi\,\mathrm{d}\mu$ to be a $\dim(D)$-dimensional form.